# Native Library SWT lib already loaded in jenkins job

Tags: jenkins, junit, swt

I build software which is a SWT based RCP application. I have some unit tests and everything runs fine on the Jenkins CI, until I add classes from the SWT lib to a test. Thn the build fails with message:

```
Could not load SWT library. Reasons: 
 no swt-gtk-4430 in java.library.path
 no swt-gtk in java.library.path
 Native Library /var/lib/jenkins/.swt/lib/linux/x86_64/libswt-gtk-4430.so already loaded in another classloader
 Can't load library: /var/lib/jenkins/.swt/lib/linux/x86_64/libswt-gtk.so
```

Does someone had the same problem and nows how to circumvent?

For example: I want to write tests which checks that some complex SWT composites are built together the right way.

**UPDATE**

A simple example test:

```
public class FooTest {
     private Composite parent = new Composite(new Shell(), SWT.NONE);
     private PartFactory sut = new PartFactory();

     @Test
     public void createPart() {
       final MPart part = sut.create(parent);
       ...
     }
  }
```

I know that I could mock out `Shell` or `Composite`. This works for some of my components. But in some cases this is not an option. How can I acchieve to use SWT classes w/o the previous mentioned error. On Windows in the IDE the Tests works fine. But it fails on the Jenkins on Linux.

The POM is not very special. The tests are executed with Surefire:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <id>test</id>
      <phase>test</phase>
      <goals>
        <goal>test</goal>
      </goals>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Can you post the setup code of one of the tests?

Comment: Do your tests run within OSGi and the workbench?

Comment: No, there is no OSGi or workbench. I want to do run simple Unittests. There is also no Setup code. I e.g. make a `new Composite(new Shell(), SWT.NONE)` and get the issue. I also tried to run the test via surefire forkmode in own JVM: No linkage error anymore, but "Could not initialize class org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display".

Comment: Can you provide more details about your build, i.e. relevant parts of pom.xml, etc. Do the tests run locally?